# Swift 4 and Alamofire - not getting all HTML data

Tags: html, alamofire, swift4

I wish to read and scrape html data from a site using Alamofire and Kanna. 
I am getting success reading and I am getting html data, but no all data from the site.
I am new to Alamofire and I have tried a couple of way to get data but always ending up with a subset of the sites data. Looking at source of the site it has more data and no special ajax or other background calls.

Code with 2 different ways to get data - same result.

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

class NetworkProxy {

    func readIbAnmalData () {
        let url = "http://ib.anmäl.com"
        let safeURL = url.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)!
        readAndParseHtml(url: safeURL)
    }

    // send request and return response data as string
    func getResponseString (url: String) {
        Alamofire.request(url).responseString { response in
            print("Request: \(String(describing: response.request))")   // original url request
            print("Response: \(String(describing: response.response))") // http url response
            debugPrint("Result: \(response.result)")                         // response serialization result

            if let data = response.data, let utf8Text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                print("Data: \(utf8Text)") // original server data as UTF8 string
            }
        }
    }

    func readAndParseHtml(url:String) {
        Alamofire.request(url).responseString { response in
            print("SUCCESS: \(response.result.isSuccess)")
            if let html = response.result.value {
                self.parseHTML(html: html)
            }
        }
    }

    func parseHTML(html:String) {
        print("HTML: \(html)")
    }
}
```

The result I am getting is:

```html
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body background="back3.png">
<br>
<br>
<br>
<center><img src="larsgarden.png"></center>
</body>
</html>
```

The site is: http://ib.xn--anml-noa.com/

I had to handle international chars in URL and add exception in my `Info.plist` in order to access a http request.

Any suggestions why I am not getting all data?
Corresponding program written in Java gets all the data.

Comment: I would say you might be getting some form of *redirection* (or AJAX calls) but then the returned HTML would need to be more complex than that. Maybe Alamofire is internally stripping some data from the HTML? Weird...

Comment: Talking to the owner of the site and according to him I get data from another site larsgarden.se. Both ib.anmäl.com and larsgarden.se has the same ip-adress and the Tomcat server transfers the request to correct place.
Can I pass along more info (request header) to get this right? It must have something to do with my request since this is working from a java-program and of course from normal web browsing.